# After Gulp, my SVGs disapper

Tags: svg, gulp

I am currently playing around with the Google Web Starter Kit and everything is working fine, but I have a few SVGs on my test page and when I Gulp the project, they do not get transferred/copied to the dist folder.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where are your SVGs stored ? If you look at the kit [gulpfile](https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js), you'll see that your svgs should be handled if they're at the root of app/, or inside images/.

Comment: They are located in images/ within app/

Comment: Hum then your svg should be picked up and come out on the other side... I would sprinkle a few [gulp-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug) in the 'images' to see what's going on (it will list the files that are being processed in the console).